# bitwise operator in php

Tags: php, operators

**Here is my code:**

```
(($order['financial_status']!='partially_refunded')?$order['fulfillments'][0]['updated_at']:null)
```

Here, I want to check,  refunded and partially_refunded by using or operator.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with bitwise operators/operations.

Comment: Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @CreativeMind: if $order['financial_status'] value should be ,not equal to partially_refuned or refunded.. I want to use | operator.

Comment: @user3671557 please check my answer out and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it's not bitwise you need, but a simple `if` conditional statement:

```
if ($order['financial_status'] !== 'partially_refunded' || 
    $order['financial_status'] !== 'refunded') {
    // Do something with $order['fulfillments'][0]['updated_at']
}
```